# How to pick with Geographic Coordinates?

Tags: gis, cesiumjs

So far, all of the examples I've seen for picking entities/features have been based on passing the window position to the pick method of the scene object. Example:

```
var pickedObject = scene.pick(movement.endPosition);
```

Is it possible to pick an object with another method which takes geographic location as its parameter?

Comment: Judging from the codebase, it appears that all picking is done from window position. Perhaps some type of method can be devised by creating a workflow which centers the view at a specific position/zoom and then picks based on a predetermined window position? I would assume that the window position wouldn't match for different clients.

Perhaps something similar, but more reliable, could be thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cesium *scene.pick* function works with window's coordinates.
If you want to pass WGS84 Geo coordinate, try this:

```
var positiongeo = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude, 0);
var screenLoc = Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates(scene, positiongeo)
var res = scene.pick(screenLoc);
```

Best Regards, Dima

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.